# Insert/Delete Columns via VBA issue

Tags: excel, vba, insert, reset

I have a workbook that was previously working with no issues. Recently, however, I have been having a problem with adding/deleting columns on visible sheets after I run certain macros.

The workbook is used for groups of members. When data is imported into the file a base number of members are included. Throughout the use of the file the group can expand or contract. I have macros that will add new members or delete existing ones. These macros simply add data or remove it from specific data sheets. Another macro is used to refresh the keycells range that is used to adjust the columns on the visible sheets.

The issue I am having is that once I either add a new member or delete one, the code to increase or delete columns on the visible sheets does not work. The macro that refreshes the sheet doesn't work, nor does manually adjusting the cell itself.

If I do not import any data and simply add or delete columns from visible sheets (based on changing the keycells value), the code runs perfectly. It seems to only occur when I import data and try using macros that add or delete members. For example, without any data, I can add in 3 members and have new columns added in to each visible sheet. I can then reduce that number manually to 1 or 2 and have the appropriate number of columns deleted for each sheet. This works fine until data is imported and the other mentioned macros are used.

I also am experiencing an issue with the file where once I receive an error, even if I reset the VBA, I cannot continue working in it. I can maneuver throughout the file, however, adding or deleting columns (by any means) does not work.  It's as though, even though the VBA was reset in the editor, the code does not exist.

This is the code that is used to refresh the keycell

```
Sub Refresh_ActivesheetB30()

    Dim dwsNames As Variant: dwsNames = Array("DATA Member-19", "DATA Sch A-19", "DATA Sch A-3-19", "DATA Sch J-19", "DATA Sch R-19", "DATA 500U-19", "DATA 500U-P-19", "DATA 500U-PA-19")

    frmWait.Show vbModeless
    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  
    Dim gws As Worksheet: Set gws = wb.Worksheets("GroupInfo")
    gws.Range("B30").Formula = "=COUNTIF('TAX INFO'!B34:B1499,"">0"")"

    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dlRow As Long
    Dim d As Long
  
    For d = LBound(dwsNames) To UBound(dwsNames)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dwsNames(d))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            dlRow = dws.Range("D" & dws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            dws.Range("A12").Copy dws.Range("A12:A" & dlRow)
            Set dws = Nothing
        End If
    Next d
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    gws.Activate
    frmWait.Hide

End Sub
```

This code adds members

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim Rng4 As Range
Dim Rng5 As Range


Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set Rng1 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox2.Value)
Set Rng2 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox6.Value)
Set Rng3 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox5.Value)
Set Rng4 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox4.Value)
Set Rng5 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox7.Value)

N = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox2, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox2) = 0 And ComboBox1 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox2 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox3.Value = "" And ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
  
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox6, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox6) = 0 And ComboBox2 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox6 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox8.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
  
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox5, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox5) = 0 And ComboBox3 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox5 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox9.Value = "" And ComboBox3.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
  
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox4, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox4) = 0 And ComboBox4 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox4 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox10.Value = "" And ComboBox4.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
  
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox7, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox7) = 0 And ComboBox5 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox7 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox11.Value = "" And ComboBox5.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else

For i = 5 To N
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox1.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng1.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox3.Text
    End If
  
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox2.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng2.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox8.Text
    End If
  
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox3.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng3.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox9.Text
    End If
  
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox4.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng4.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox10.Text
    End If
  
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox5.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng5.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox11.Text
    End If
Next i

End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


Unload frmAddAdj



End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox", "ComboBox"
                ctl.Text = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
                ctl.Value = False
        End Select
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim iRow As Integer, iMax As Integer

iRow = Cells.Find(What:="New Jersey Audit Adjustment", _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

iMax = Cells.Find(What:="New Jersey Audit Adjustment", _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
  
If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox3.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox4.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox5.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
  
Else
    Me.ComboBox1.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox2.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox3.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox4.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox5.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
  
End If
End Sub
```

This is the code to delete members

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'declare the variables
    Dim Findvalue As Range, DeleteRange As Range
    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim cNum As Integer
    Dim Search As String, FirstAddress As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
  
  
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA Member-19")

  
'error statement
    On Error Resume Next
  
    Search = TextBox6.Value
'check for control from listbox dblclick values
    If TextBox6.Value = "" Or Search = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is not data to delete", 48
        Exit Sub
    Else
'find the employees number row
        Set Findvalue = ws.Range("D:D").Find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not Findvalue Is Nothing Then
'mark first address
        FirstAddress = Findvalue.Address
'give the user a chance to change their mind!
            Response = MsgBox(Search & Chr(10) & _
            "Are you sure that you want to delete this Member?", 292, "Are you sure?")
            If Response = vbYes Then
'find all matching records
            Do
                If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set DeleteRange = Findvalue
                Else
                    Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, Findvalue)
                End If
            Set Findvalue = ws.Range("D:D").FindNext(Findvalue)
            Loop While FirstAddress <> Findvalue.Address
          
'delete record(s)
            DeleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
              
'clear the user form controls
                cNum = 12
                For x = 1 To cNum
                    Me.Controls("Reg" & x).Value = ""
                Next
              
'Employee deleted from the database
                MsgBox Search & Chr(10) & "The Member has been deleted successfully.", 64, "Record Deleted"
              
'add the values to the listbox
               lstLookup.RowSource = ""
              
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox Search & Chr(10) & "Record Not Found", 48, "Not Found"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload frmDeleteMembers19


End Sub
```

This is the code that goes into the main sheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
                                                                                                                                           
    Dim KeyCells As Range, colNum As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
        SOMESHEETS = "*C-Proposal-19*MemberInfo-19*Schedule J-19*NOL-19*NOL-P-19*NOL-PA-19*Schedule R-19*Schedule A-3-19*Schedule A-19*Schedule H-19*"
        Set KeyCells = Range("B30")
        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
            If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
                colNum = KeyCells.Value
                If colNum > 0 Then
                 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                     If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                     If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=colNum
                     End If
                     End If
                 Next ws
                End If
            End If
        End If
      

  
    SOMESHEETS = "*MemberInfo-20*C-Proposal-20*Schedule J-20*NOL-20*Schedule R-20*NOL-P-20*SchA-3-20*Schedule H-20*NOL-PA-20*Schedule A-20*Schedule A-5-20*"
    Set KeyCells = Range("B36")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
            colNum = KeyCells.Value
            If colNum > 0 Then
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                    If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=colNum
                    End If
                    End If
                Next ws
            End If
        End If
    End If
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And this is the general code that each sheet pulls from. I only included on sheet to save some space, but each sheet has similar code.

```
Public Sub InsertColumnsOnSheet(ByVal argSheet As Worksheet, ByVal argColNum As Long)

    Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim TotalCol As Long, LeftFixedCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  
Set ws = Worksheets("C-Proposal-19")
    With argSheet
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, 6), .Cells(3, .Columns.Count))
        Set c = Rng.Find("GROSS")
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            TotalCol = c.Column
            LeftFixedCol = 5
            j = .Range("B4").End(xlToRight).Column
            k = j - LeftFixedCol
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            If TotalCol < LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Then
                    .Columns(j).Copy
                    .Columns(j + 1).Resize(, argColNum - k).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
            End If
            If TotalCol > LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Then
                For i = TotalCol - 1 To LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Step -1
                    .Columns(i).Delete
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Moreover, if I add a member and refresh the keycells range, a new column will be added. If I then try to reduce the amount of columns manually, it will reduce the amount of columns. The issue pops up when I try use the delete macro. After I delete out the member through that macro, I cannot add or delete columns, either manually or through the refresh macro.

There also seems to be an issue where if I have an error pop up with VBA, the workbook does not use the code that I have in it. For example, if I change the general code to add/delete columns and I get an error, even if I reset the VBA in the editor, if I try and change the keycells nothing happens. I don't get the same error again, even though I don't change the code at all, and nothing happens to any of the sheets.

Comment: "does not work" and "an error" are not telling us much about *exactly what happens* when you run your code...   What error do you get, and on which line?  There's so much code there we're not really going to be able to figure it out without more details.

Comment: Are you trying to sync column headers based on a master sheet?  Does the column order matter?

Comment: Does formatting matter?

Comment: @TimWilliams What's happening is that once I use the delete member userform, I cannot add or delete columns on any sheet.  Everything else still works, however, refreshing the keycells range, either manually or through the macro, does not have any effect on the workbook

Comment: @TimWilliams Also, the does not work and an error comments mean that if I get any error with the VBA while I'm editing it then the code that is used to adjust the columns based on the keycells range does nothing.  I do not get any errors again, and the code does nothing.  No new columns are created or deleted

Comment: Does the event handler even fire when you change one of the triggering cells?  Note if you use `Application.EnableEvents = False` and your code crashes before executing `Application.EnableEvents = True` then events will *remain off* until you either execute `Application.EnableEvents = True` or you restart Excel.  This is why it's important to always use an error handler to ensure events get re-enabled.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the first part of your code:

```vb
    For d = LBound(dwsNames) To UBound(dwsNames)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dwsNames(d))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            dlRow = dws.Range("D" & dws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            dws.Range("A12").Copy dws.Range("A12:A" & dlRow)
            Set dws = Nothing
        End If
    Next d
```

This shows the problem:

```vb
    Dim ws As Worksheet, e
    
    For Each e In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(e)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then Debug.Print e, ws.Name
    Next e
```

Run in a workbook which contains only `Sheet1`, it gives this output:

```txt
Sheet1        Sheet1
Sheet2        Sheet1    'oops!
```

So you need to add `Set dws = Nothing` before running `Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dwsNames(d))`